# Weblinks are not responsive in mobile page

Tags: css, wordpress

Weblinks are not responsive, they increased the mobile page width and create bad user experience.

I am using Asona theme.

Fix this problem, the weblinks doesn't bend and goes on next paragraph, they are just goes straight.[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using the [overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property to break the string enabling it to wrap onto a new line.

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in cases like these, people will just want to *click*  the link and not *read* it, you could simply use `overflow: hidden` on the direct container, i.e. the `li`s of that list.

And you could also add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to make clear that the link is longer than what is visible on the screen:

```css
ul.link_list li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

ul.link_list {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Link List</h4>
<ul class="link_list">
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/kjhadfkjh/oiuwoijwrv/ljnsvkjns/oiwueroiuwe/kjnsdvkjn/llksuerlkulku/lkamsclkm/lkjaelrkjl">https://www.example.com/kjhadfkjh/oiuwoijwrv/ljnsvkjns/oiwueroiuwe/kjnsdvkjn/llksuerlkulku/lkamsclkm/lkjaelrkjl</a></li>
</ul>
```